# openni_tracker with "Kinect for Windows"

Tags: kinect, openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im trying to start the openni_tracker ( with rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker) and get this error messages:

```
[ERROR] [1339081305.103259848]: Find user generator failed: This operation is invalid!
```

and sometimes this error message

```
[ERROR] [1339081089.497960592]: InitFromXml failed: Got a timeout while waiting for a network command to complete!
```

With the debugger I got this output:

```
user@hpcname:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_tracker/bin$ gdb openni_tracker
Reading symbols from /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_tracker/bin/openni_tracker...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_tracker/bin/openni_tracker 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0x7ffff14b0700 (LWP 18459)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff0caf700 (LWP 18460)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff04ae700 (LWP 18461)]
[New Thread 0x7fffefcad700 (LWP 18466)]
[New Thread 0x7fffed0fc700 (LWP 18468)]

[ERROR] [1339081305.103259848]: Find user generator failed: This operation is invalid!

[Thread 0x7fffefcad700 (LWP 18466) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff04ae700 (LWP 18461) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff14b0700 (LWP 18459) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff0caf700 (LWP 18460) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffed0fc700 (LWP 18468) exited]
[Inferior 1 (process 18455) exited with code 022]

(gdb) l
127 /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-openni-tracker-0.1.0/debian/ros-fuerte-openni-tracker/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_tracker/src/openni_tracker.cpp: File or dictionary not found.
    in /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-openni-tracker-0.1.0/debian/ros-fuerte-openni-tracker/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_tracker/src/openni_tracker.cpp
```

**Update:**

At begin, I´ve changed the openni drivers to adapt the ["Kinect for Windows"](http://answers.ros.org/question/12876/kinect-for-windows/) and I found out, that the NITE drivers are not compatible anymore with the openni drivers. That is the reason why I got this openni_tracker errors in my case.

So, I changed my ROS-System again to Electric and removed the adapted openni kinect drivers from my system. There the Kinect for Xbox works fine again with the openni_tracker.

**Conclusion for now:**

It is possbile to adapt the "K4W" in ROS to get the video data stream. As soon as the **openni_tracker** should be used there are some compatibility errors under Electric and Fuerte.

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35956/openni_tracker-with-%22kinect-for-windows%22/) by [GermanUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2107/germanuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2012-06-07

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suppose a bug in openni. I tested NiViewer. The frist start is ok. Then I exit the NiViewer and start it again. So I get this error: "Open failed: Got a timeout while waiting for a network command to complete!". Sometimes it is possible to restart once, so I get this error after the 3rd start.

After a reboot I have again one or two successful starts.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm also using Fuerte, fresh install. I'm getting the exact same error message. Does this stack not work with Fuerte?

---

Originally posted by [punching](https://answers.ros.org/users/1882/punching/) with karma: 78 on 2012-06-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can confirm that the Problem is also given for the Xition Pro Live camera. My fresh installed Ubuntu 12.04 lts 64 bit does complain about dummy threads which do not have any attributes, e.g.:

> Exception AttributeError:
> AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object
> has no attribute  '_Thread__block'",)
> in <module 'threading' from
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'>
> ignored

Further does the driver not find/load the xition:

> 1. device on bus 002:07 is a Xtion Pro (600) from ASUS (1d27) with serial id
>    '' [ INFO] [1340293305.271033061]:
>    Searching for device with index = 1 [
>    INFO] [1340293309.278407567]: No
>    matching device found.... waiting for
>    devices. Reason:
>    openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::OpenNIDevice(xn::Context&,
>    const xn::NodeInfo&, const
>    xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&) @
>    /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-openni-camera-1.8.0/debian/ros-fuerte-openni-camera/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp
>    @ 99 : creating depth generator
>    failed. Reason: Got a timeout while
>    waiting for a network command to
>    complete!

**Edit 1:**

The System:

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64Bit (fresh installation) and installed fuerte.
The machine itself is an Intel® Core™ i7 CPU Q 820 @ 1.73GHz × 8 with 8GB-Ram.

The same machine was already in use with diamond and electirc and worked well. The Xition PRO Live was also used a lot  with the former ROS versions.

The lsusb log is:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0765:5001 X-Rite, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c526 Logitech, Inc. Nano Receiver
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 17ef:480f Lenovo Integrated Webcam [R5U877]
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 17ef:1003 Lenovo Integrated Smart Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 056a:00e2 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 1d27:0600
```

The Problem:

Using fuerte and the command:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

the sensor is not running correctly. Instead the system produces the following log:

```
    SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /camera/depth/rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/disparity_depth/max_range
 * /camera/disparity_depth/min_range
 * /camera/disparity_depth_registered/max_range
 * /camera/disparity_depth_registered/min_range
 * /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url
 * /camera/driver/depth_frame_id
 * /camera/driver/depth_registration
 * /camera/driver/device_id
 * /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url
 * /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /camera/depth/
    metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    points (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/rgb/
    debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)
  /
    camera_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/
    disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_depth_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    driver (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
    register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/ir/
    rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet)
  /camera/depth_registered/
    metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [12791]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 58fb0952-bc60-11e1-8774-f0def12b9fd5
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [12804]
started core service [/rosout]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera_nodelet_manager-2]: started with pid [12816]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/driver-3]: started with pid [12817]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/rgb/debayer-4]: started with pid [12835]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/rgb/rectify_mono-5]: started with pid [12877]
[ INFO] [1340365781.919819166]: Initializing nodelet with 8 worker threads.
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/rgb/rectify_color-6]: started with pid [12926]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/ir/rectify_ir-7]: started with pid [12983]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/depth/rectify_depth-8]: started with pid [13004]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/depth/metric_rect-9]: started with pid [13024]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/depth/metric-10]: started with pid [13110]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/depth/points-11]: started with pid [13133]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-12]: started with pid [13191]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth-13]: started with pid [13211]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/depth_registered/metric_rect-14]: started with pid [13268]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/depth_registered/metric-15]: started with pid [13288]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb-16]: started with pid [13348]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/disparity_depth-17]: started with pid [13397]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera/disparity_depth_registered-18]: started with pid [13450]
[ INFO] [1340365783.810701746]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1340365783.810950160]: 1. device on bus 002:05 is a PrimeSense Device (600) from PrimeSense (1d27) with serial id ''
[ INFO] [1340365783.812012099]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1340365783.848843552]: Opened 'PrimeSense Device' on bus 2:5 with serial number ''
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera_base_link-19]: started with pid [13492]
[ INFO] [1340365783.894937306]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1340365783.895045111]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame' 
[ WARN] [1340365783.901893363]: Camera calibration file /home/tlinder/.ros/camera_info/rgb.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1340365783.902022187]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1340365783.902136407]: Camera calibration file /home/tlinder/.ros/camera_info/depth.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1340365783.902228154]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera_base_link1-20]: started with pid [13655]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera_base_link2-21]: started with pid [13719]
[ERROR] [1340365784.275375381]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1340365784.284126089]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[camera_base_link3-22]: started with pid [13765]
```

As you can se in the few first lines even the ROS-Master has some problems to start correctly:

```
auto-starting new master Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored process[master]: started with pid [12791]
```

Some college of mine informed me that he noticed problems with Python under Ubuntu 12.04. So may this is the source of issues.

---

Originally posted by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) with karma: 663 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) on 2012-06-21**:
Hi, could you provide further details? What commands trigger these errors, etc. Providing a log from lsusb command can be helpful as well.

**Comment by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) on 2012-06-22**:
Hi, I don't see any kinect in the output of your lsusb. It should be anything similar to this: http://answers.ros.org/question/36921/openni_tracker-timeout-error-in-fuerte-ubuntu-1204/ (look at the end of the question).

**Comment by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) on 2012-06-22**:
Well the Xition pro live has no human readable name in the LSUSB log. But the device is still there "Bus 002 Device 007: ID 1d27:0600"

**Comment by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) on 2012-06-22**:
OK, can you test if you have the same error when you execute rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker? Anyway, I've created a bug report. Let's hope it's solved soon.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2012-07-13**:
I suppose a bug in openni.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since it seems that this is a Fuerte issue, I've posted a ticket in the bug tracker: https://kforge.ros.org/openni/trac/ticket/53

---

Originally posted by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) with karma: 396 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1